# firefox not displaying styles of html file

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>A CSS Exercise</title>
<style type=”text/css”>
div {
font-weight: bold;
}
span {
font-style: italic;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>This is my web page.</div>
<div>This is the <span>nicest</span> page I’ve made yet.</div>
<div>Here is some text on my page.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[The output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc7vQ.png)

i am using mozilla firefox in ubuntu 12.04,using apache web server

Comment: It's not working because of the quotes around `text/css`... change `”` to `"`, or just remove the `type` attribute since it's not required in HTML5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using these `”` instead of these `"` around your type attribute. 
You can either use those `"` or those `'` , but never those `”`.

Also, just in case you are new, put your css in an extra file anyway if possible ;)

EDIT: Just saw someone else posted the answer faster than me

Answer (score 0):

You are using the "type" attribute incorrectly. Replace the quotes with the correct ones or remove the attribute entirely. This will work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>A CSS Exercise</title>
<style>
div {
font-weight: bold;
}
span {
font-style: italic;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>This is my web page.</div>
<div>This is the <span>nicest</span> page I've made yet.</div>
<div>Here is some text on my page.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You might want to check some examples over at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp